# Multiple file input batch remove newline

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

I am trying to change the script; instead of adding a line to `file.txt`, I want to do it for all `*.txt` files inside the directory. This script removes new lines and adds a comma to separate.

Any help appreciated.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "line="


for /F "delims=" %%a in (inputfile.txt) do set "line=!line!,%%a"

echo !line:~1!>>outputfile.txt
```

**MY input file im trying to use is the below csv**
2019-05-29 08:03:48,TiltA,3.420,19.9,0.5017,0.6903
2019-05-29 09:03:48,TiltB,3.420,19.9,0.3017,0.6903
2019-05-29 08:03:48,TiltC,3.420,19.9,0.5017,0.6903
2019-05-29 09:03:48,TiltD,3.420,19.9,0.3017,0.6903
2019-05-29 08:03:48,TiltE,3.420,19.9,0.5017,0.6903

Comment: These kind of questions are suitable for StackOverflow, not SuperUser.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to accomplish. You want to remove new lines? Where are the new lines coming from? Why are you trying to set the `line` variable twice?

Comment: I have a csv coming from a data logger. Every entry is on a new line. My input to another program requires everything to be on one line to be read. I have made this work by the above code. Now i am trying to apply it to *.* all files but all i get is it printing ~1

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarifying! This should get you in the right direction:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\Your\Directory"
set "dirs=C:\Your\Output\Folder"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "%dir%" %%A in (*.txt) do (
    set "new=%%~nA"
    if exist "%dirs%\!new!.txt" del /f /q "%dirs%\!new!.txt"
    for /f %%B in (%%A) do (
        echo|set /p="%%B,"
    ) >> "%dirs%\!new!.txt"
)
```

I highly recommend having a different output folder unless you're wanting to overwrite your source txt files - so this is what I've come up with. The first loop will go through all of your txt files in the specified directory (`for /r %dir%`) and set the name of each of those as variable `new`; immediately after that it will check for the existence of that `new` txt file in your output directory and delete it - this is a crucial step because we have to use `>>` to output all the `%%B` parameters on a single line, since `>` will overwrite all of the previous entries. If you don't delete any potential `new` txt file created from previously running the script, it will duplicate the entries on the line. After that is taken care of we have a nested for-loop that takes the information from the text file and uses `echo|set /p` to put each `%%B` on the same line with a `,`. With this basic script, there will be a trailing `,` that you may or may not want to get rid of - otherwise, I believe this will accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and looks like it should work but i tried to play around with this way of doing it but couldn't get it to output anything

Comment: are you making your output directory different from your source directory?

Comment: yes i used a subfolder in my current folder but it didnt create any files. i also tried to make it the same output/input folder but it deleted all the .txt files.

Comment: your right it works, but it dosn't like the space in the first column. This causes it to keep repeating the same date over and over.

Comment: ah - so the data logger adds a blank column for each entry in the .csv file? - or does it just include spaces and other information?

Comment: In the timestamp column it has a space between the time and the date :/

Comment: if you don't mind: could you edit your question with another code block of an example entry from one of your txt files that has its data on multiple lines? you can replace the data with random stuff - I think it will help to be able to see the format of the txt file before trying to echo on one line